# What is $x <1000$ such that $x =37a+8=43b+11$?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is $x$? How to solve this without modular arithmetics and without brute force?

Comment: Why exclude all the standard methods?

Comment: I just want to know other ways

Comment: Diophantine equation?

Comment: Yes, something like that, how would solve this, with diophantine equation?

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-diophantine-equations-one-equation/#:~:text=Linear%20Diophantine%20Equations,degree%20equation%20of%20this%20type.

Comment: The chinese remainder theorem is the best method for this. Any reason why you do not allow it ?

Comment: I know, but it's long

Comment: Long ? It gives the solution immediate.

Comment: Well, then my perspective to this method and knowledge is bad

Comment: Okay, then how would you solve this with Chinese reminder theorem?

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted, tonmath?

Comment: no, it’s great, just maybe more detail would be even better

Comment: Better, tonmath?

Comment: Yes, great! I like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$37a+8=43b+11$,
$37a+8=37b+6b+11$,
$37(a-b)=6b+3$,
$a-b+6(6a-6b)=6b+3$,
$a-b=6(7b-6a)+3$.
Let $7b-6a=0$, so $b=6t$ and $a=7t$ for some integer $t$.
Then $a-b=7t-6t=t$,
but also $a-b=3$,
so $t=3$,
$a=7t=21$,
$b=6t=18$,
$x=37\times21+8=43\times18+11=785$.